# Nivo Slider Links do not Work in IE8

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, slider, nivo-slider

I've installed the newest version of Nivo Slider, 3.2, on my website and it works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE8 the slide links do not work. I have searched and tried a bunch of solutions, such as adding to my CSS:

```
.nivoSlider a, .nivoSlider img {
    display: block !important;
}
```

But that only works on the first image of the slider, the rest of the images do not link to their assigned pages.

My site is [here](http://www.psndealer.com/dealersite/default.asp?dom=UNITEDTRUCKCENTERS), click "Truck Sales" up top

CSS is [here](http://www.psndealer.com/dealersite/images/UNITEDTRUCKCENTERS/default.css)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this product *supposed* to work with IE8?  If so, a bug report should be submitted to the authors.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with nivo slider, add the following css:

```css
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink{
    display:none;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity:0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink img{
    display:block!important;
}
```

It happens because IE has problem rendering an empty `<a>` without a background.. I've ran into this when a long time ago I wanted to place a link over a flash element. giving it a background and setting opacity to 0 will make it work correctly without harming the design.

Comment: Hi, this only works for the first image, in the rest of the images, the link does not work. Please try it: http://www.psndealer.com/dealersite/default.asp?dom=UNITEDTRUCKCENTERS then click "Truck Sales."

Comment: Do you know that you break javascript when using `console` on browsers that don't support it? this could be related. the css i gave you should work for all slides

Comment: What is console? Sorry, I do not know what it is. Is there a way to make JavaScript or jQuery work with it? If you open my site with IE8, you'll see that only the first slide has a link using your solution.

Comment: I've tried opening you site with IETester since I don't have IE8 on my machine and it immidiately crashed with javascript errors

Comment: It does not do that with an installed version of IE8, try a portable version maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, but I found another solution:

```
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:6;
    display:none;
    background:white;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /other than IE/
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity:0;
    opacity: 0;
    line-height: 375px; /*Change this to the height of your image*/
    font-size: 0px;
}

.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink img{
    display:block!important;
}
```

Now add some text in front of each image link:

```
<a href="yourlink.php">TEXT GOES HERE<img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
```

It's a little hacky but it does the trick. -Cheers